# How to write relative permittivity in text

Tags: symbols

I'd like to use these two symbols in the text of my thesis. How would I write them?

[image] & 
[image]

Comment: `$\varepsilon_\mathrm{r}$  \& $\varepsilon_0$` is the way to do inline math for these terms.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You are right. I thought it was provided by `amsmath` and I'm pretty sure this once used to be the case. I don't have Lamport's book with me. I'll look it up later.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Lamport, p.43, `\varepsilon`, `\vartheta`, `\varpi`, `\varsigma`, `\varphi`.

Comment: Haha, thanks for all the input. Would anybody still be so nice to post it as an actual answer so I can mark the question answered :D ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks again. I couldn't find my copy of Lamport but according to Scott Pakin's Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, they're plain LaTeX. (Now I must find that book...)

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX provides, as any new user finds out, support for greek letters in math mode, with macro names that are spelled out: `\alpha`, `\beta`, `\delta`, etc.

Unfortunately, the default appearance of `\epsilon` is

[image]

which is not what the OP was seeking.

However, one finds on p.43 of Lamport's LaTeX User Guide that several greek letters have variants that are available through standard LaTeX.  Namely, `\varepsilon`, `\vartheta`, `\varpi`, `\varsigma`, `\varphi`.

A comparison of the standard versus the variant forms is given below:

[image]

We find that, indeed, `\varepsilon` is the desired form of the OP.

Other details about the OP's question were the inclusion of subscripts  These are done in math mode, with the subscript following a `_` character; however, only a single character is typically absorbed into the subscript (e.g., `\varepsilon_0`), so that longer subscripts should be grouped in braces as `\varepsilon_{xy}`.  In the case of one of the OP's examples, an upright `r` was requested as the subscript.  If one used `\varepsilon_r`, the `r` would be in standard math mode, which is italic

[image]

However, one can ask for upright math mode by way of `\mathrm{}` (math-roman), which already comes pre-grouped, so that `\varepsilon_\mathrm{r}` yields

[image]

The only final thing to mention, which is very introductory, is that *inline* math (so-called `\textstyle`) is accessed by way of dollar delimiters `$...$`, or in many ways more preferably, `\(...\)` delimiters.  If one wants the math on a line by itself (so-called `\displaystyle`), with no efforts to compress the expression into a single row height, then `\[...\]` delimiters are used, or else one of the many LaTeX math environments such as `equation` or the `amsmath.sty` environments in the `align` family.

Thus, to achieve the OP's request, I provide the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\varepsilon_\mathrm{r}$ and $\varepsilon_0$ are inline expressions
\end{document}
```

[image]